# How to catch errors thrown from "FilesInterceptor" decorator

Tags: express, file-upload, nestjs, multer, interceptor

I'm using the NestJS `@FilesInterceptor` to parse an array of files in a multipart request, here's how I use it:

```
@FilesInterceptor('files', 3, { some other options })
```

I need a specific error to be thrown if more than 3 files are sent, but what I get is a socket hangup client-side

```
Error: socket hang up
```

and this is the error logged in the console of the server:

```
Error: Unexpected end of multipart data
```

In the end: server crashed :(

So, how can I catch this error to handle it and prevent crashing?

- It doesn't seem to be an instance of `HttpException` so the exception filter is not useful.
- I could have done the length check in the controller, but I need `{ some other options }`, so I must set a value for the `maxCount`

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem: the server has a global interceptor that implements a timeout for incoming requests. If I remove it, then the error is parsed correctly to an `HttpException` the client gets a `BadRequest` as expected 
I'm still confused about why this doesn't work when I put it all together...

Comment: I've quickly fixed this by putting `undefined` as `maxCount` and counting the files in the controller even if I would like to know how to properly use `maxCount`